# My local react can not store the express session in remote server

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, express-session

I am facing the issue that can not store the cookie session in the localhost frontend. My remote API server and remote frontend server have been working well with the current setup, but when I develop a new feature in the frontend I want to get results from the API server but I can not store a cookie session in Chrome
here is my API server config session, can anyone suggest me a solution?

```
const pathSessionCheck =
    (fn: CallableFunction) => (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) =>
        ['/api/m/', '/api/auth', '/api/login', '/api/sess', '/api/logout'].some((uripath) => req.path.includes(uripath))
            ? fn(req, res, next)
            : next()
app.use(
        pathSessionCheck(
            session({
                secret: systemConfig.SESS_SEC,
                store: new SequelizeStore({
                    db: db.sequelize,
                    table: db.models.sessions.name,
                    tableName: db.models.sessions.tableName,
                    checkExpirationInterval: 60 * 60 * 1000
                }),
                name: systemConfig.SESS_NAME,
                resave: false,
                saveUninitialized: false,
                cookie: {
                    sameSite: 'lax',
                    maxAge: 86400000 * 7,
                    secure: false
                }
            })
        )
    )
```